# NSUnknownkey exception not raised everytime at the same place in code , Why?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a ViewController which has a corresponding .xib for view. Now in that .xib file there are certain UILabels which DO NOT exist in header file, meaning that they were removed from header but still appear yellow(warning) in .xib.

When I run this code, it sometimes runs fine but sometimes it crashes with following error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key messagesLabel.'

I know the solution but what I want to understand is why is the code not crashing everytime?

Attached is the screenshot of .xib file

[image]

Comment: It only crashes if the label is loaded. Maybe you have code that loads the label that's not run everytime?

Comment: @JackWu label loads everytime.